# Properly designing database structure in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to ask what would be your approach to this.

In short, the application has a few roles, Admins Teachers, and Students.

The school year begins on a specific date and it ends on one. Example 1.9.2021 till 20.6.2022.
Every student has tests, and results are supposed to be managed by a teacher. By default test, results are recorded 2 times a year.

Every test result is in seconds, and then you have a table with min-max values for each gender and age which you can use to compare with current results.

Then later on each student has a record so called Archive where he can see his previous records. How can I achieve this?

Currently using Laravel 8.7 with PHP 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might know, in MVC (Model-View-Controller) frameworks, the model is in fact a database entity, the controller is where your application logic is located, and the view shows the data to the user.

So, for your application, I recommend the follwing structure:

Models:

- Admin
- Teacher
- Student
- Semester
- Test
- TestResult

Controllers:

- AdminController
- TeacherController
- StudentController
- SemesterController
- TestController
- TestResultController

You can decide which views are necessary.

For example:

- students_list
- student_info
- test_results

Let me know if you needed more explanation

Answer (score 1):

add different models as User, School, SchoolSession, SchoolSessionTest, SchoolSessionTestQuestion, SchoolSessionTestResult
relations should be pretty self-explanatory from the name of the models
table with min-max values can be achieved by some group by query on your User model.